# I got this "glass" effect after i applied a material on some branches in blender 2.91

Tags: mesh, materials, modifiers

[EDITORS NOTE - This problem is occurring with an Nvidia GPU, and is not related to the current AMD Driver issue.]

[image]

[image]

I have 2 branches, and I made a group with those two. The first one worked great, but the second got a very weird glass effect, and not just that one, after I applied the texture in a copy of the first one, it didn't work.

I want to mention that the second one didn't have the body (like gray or something, like the cube from the startup), it was kinda clear.

[image]

Comment: @ChristopherBennett 
no, it's not that, i have Nvidia, in the rest, it works, If I create another blender file and I'm making a cube or something i can see it, but only that thing doesn't work... it's not visible in the solid mode and material preview... and only that one...

Comment: Oh, weird. I've seen this (a very similar thing) happen hundreds of times with AMD gpu's but this is a first for Nvidia. Is your texture using an alpha?

Comment: idk i'm a beginner. How i see that?

Comment: Nevermind, that's likely not the problem anyway. It's possible you changed a viewport setting for the object, or it's possible something just happened to that file (rare, but possible). It's hard to tell without looking at the project. You can upload it here so we can have a look if you want - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (Just edit your own question and paste in the link they give you)

Comment: ok I will do it, do I have to put the whole file? or just the blender file itself?

Comment: Just the project file (.blend) should do.

Comment: done, i hope it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117740/discussion-between-timo132019-and-christopher-bennett).